# How do you show $\frac{\epsilon \sin(\epsilon t)}{1-\epsilon t } = \mathcal{O(\epsilon ^2)} \quad (1 \leq t \leq 1000)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How do you show $\frac{\epsilon \sin(\epsilon t)}{1-\epsilon t } = \mathcal{O(\epsilon ^2)}\quad (\epsilon \to 0) \quad (1 \leq t \leq 1000)$. Bit lost on the relevance of the range of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

What could be
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{\varepsilon \sin(\varepsilon t)}{\varepsilon ^2(1-\varepsilon t)} \ \ ?$$

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the notation $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(g(x))$ means that $f(x)$ is asymptotically bounded by $g(x)$ in the neighbourhood of some point with respect to some constant multiplier of $g(x)$. In your case you have two functions to consider:
$$
f(\epsilon) = \frac{\epsilon\sin(\epsilon t)}{1-\epsilon t}\\
g(\epsilon) = \epsilon^2
$$

What you want to show is that:
$$
\left|\frac{f(\epsilon)}{g(\epsilon)}\right| \le C \in \Bbb R
$$

In such case:
$$
\frac{\epsilon\sin(\epsilon t)}{\epsilon^2(1-\epsilon t)} = \frac{\sin(\epsilon t)}{\epsilon(1-\epsilon t)}
$$

Now let's take a look at what happens around $\epsilon = 0$:
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to0}\frac{\sin(\epsilon t)}{\epsilon(1-\epsilon t)} = \\
\lim_{\epsilon \to0}\frac{\sin(\epsilon t)\cdot t}{\epsilon t(1-\epsilon t)} = \\
\lim_{\epsilon \to0}\frac{t}{(1-\epsilon t)} = t \in[1, 1000]
$$